# jQuery - Loop string array based on count

Tags: php, jquery, arrays

**Sample String Output**

```
[{v:5, f:'Week 1'}, {v:10, f:'Week 2'},{v:15, f:'Week 3'},{v:20, f:'Week 4'},{v:25, f:'Week 5'}]
```

**Snippet**

```
function weekAxis(){

var ticks = '';
var week_count = <?php echo $chart ?>; //count number of weeks

    for(i=0; i<=week_count; i++){

        var tick_str[] = '{v:'+week_count, f:'Week' +week_count}';
    }
return ticks;

}
```

**Desired Output based on week count**

If `week_count` = `5`,

```
var ticks = [{v:5, f:'Week 1'}, {v:10, f:'Week 2'},{v:15, f:'Week 3'},{v:20, f:'Week 4'},{v:25, f:'Week 5'}]
```

If `week_count` = `4`,

```
var  ticks = [{v:4, f:'Week 1'}, {v:8, f:'Week 2'},{v:12, f:'Week 3'},{v:16, f:'Week 4'}]
```

If `week_count` = `6`,

```
var  ticks = [{v:6, f:'Week 1'}, {v:12, f:'Week 2'},{v:18, f:'Week 3'}, {v:24, f:'Week 4'}, {v:30, f:'Week 5'}, {v:36, f:'Week 6'}]
```

As observed, the value of `v` is multiplied with count itself and will loop till it reaches the week count. Similarly, `Week` text will have incremented counter value.

How can I make above string based on week count passed ?

Comment: You've tagged your question `jquery`, but I don't see anything related to jQuery at all in the question. I *do* see what I assume is PHP code; are you trying to do this in PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this : You can initialize an array and push map into it. In for loop, create map with count and `i` variable as shown below.

```js
function weekAxis(){
    
    var ticks = new Array();
    var week_count = 4; //count number of weeks
    
        for(i=1; i<=week_count; i++){
            var tick_str = {};
            tick_str['v'] = ( week_count * i );
            tick_str['f'] = 'Week ' + i ;
            ticks.push(tick_str);
        }
    return ticks;
    
    }

alert(JSON.stringify(weekAxis()));
```

Comment: It says `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement var tick_str['v'] = week_count * i ;`

Comment: Sorry i have put `var` multiple times, corrected now. please try.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick

```
function weekAxis(){
    var ticks = '',week_count = 5,tick_str = [];
    for(i=0; i<week_count; i++){
        var ex = {
            v:week_count*(i+1),
            f:'Week'+week_count
        };
        tick_str.push(ex);
    }
    return JSON.stringify(tick_str);
}
```